# IDEA как скопировать сообщение об ошибке?

Tags: intellij-idea

Я про это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ctrl + с = не работает, после выделения, окно сразу закрывается
Ctrl+Alt+ левый клики мыши, как пишут некоторые - тоже не работает

Comment: Попробуйте выделить мышкой, а потом кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать "копировать"

Comment: Текст сообщения дублируется в  окне `Problems` - там стандартная комбинация **Ctrl+C** работает без проблем.

Comment: Нет  Ctrl+С не работает. Также не  работает выделение + копировать. Любое действие (нажатие на любую кнопку, клик и т.д) - моментально закрывает окно без копирования